# Quit running screen on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, pause

I know you can do Control+C to force quit it, but say I am running a program on the screen such as a Minecraft server... how do I leave the screen while in SSH without shutting off the screen/server?

Is there a shortcut?

I doubt I can type any commands, since the Minecraft program is a console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could run the process in [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) and detach the screen session - <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> in screen or <kbd>f6</kbd> in byobu

Comment: That was it! Thank you. - CentOS 6 (64 Bit)

Answer (score 4):

`nohup` or `screen` are the way to go if you haven't started the process yet - the earlier captures the output for you in a file, while the latter is more complex and allows you to resume control of the process in a latter connection ([learning GNU Screen](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/introduction-to-gnu-screen/) is really worth it). If you are already running it and you don't want to quit and restart it, though, you can do the following:

- Suspend the process with `ctrl-Z`
- Resume it in the background with `bg`.
- Disown it (detach it from the current shell) with `disown %1`

Now the process isn't related to your TTY anymore and you can safely disconnect from the server.

Answer (score 3):

You want to nohup the server and run it in the background. `nohup minecraftserver &`

Nohup keeps the system from killing the process when you log out of your shell and the `&` at the end runs it in the background.